# a pitfall in argument and interface inheritance in fsharp

Tags: f#, unit-type

Is there any real reason why KO would not work ?

```
  type IBase = 
      abstract member test : (unit * unit) -> unit

  type OK() = 
      interface IBase with

        member x.test ((titi,tata)) = () //OK

  type KO() = 
      interface IBase with

        member x.test (titi,tata) = () //fail : This override takes a different number of arguments to the corresponding abstract member
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the parentheses *mean* something in F# (it indicates a tuple), so they're not the same.

As given, the `test` method is defined as a method that takes a *tuple* of two `unit` values as arguments. If you use Reflection to get the MethodInfo, the method is defined as:

```
Void test(System.Tuple`2[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit])
```

That matches the `OK` method, but not the `KO` method.

If you redefine the interface to

```
type IBase = 
    abstract member test : unit * unit -> unit
```

Then `OK` doesn't compile, but `KO` does.

This alternative version produces a `test` method which takes two arguments:

```
Void test(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit)
```

Comment: Is the repl incorrect then? This is the type it gives for the `OK` class: `type OK =
  class
    interface IBase
    new : unit -> OK
  end`

Comment: Not at all. What it's telling you is that `OK` is a class that implements the interface `IBase` and has the member `new`, which is takes `unit` as input and returns `OK` as the output - this member is also in OO known as a *constructor*; it has nothing to do with the `IBase` interface.

Comment: Nah, I had to do a double-take on it myself :)

Comment: Moderately annoying that the override of the member doesn't show up in the subclass definition.

Answer (score 6):

```
abstract member test : (unit * unit) -> unit
```

> Parentheses can be used to group complex parameters, such as when a
>   function type is a parameter, or to indicate when a tuple is treated
>   as a single parameter rather than as two parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483468.aspx

Because of the parentheses your abstract method expects a parameter which is a tuple of 2 units, rather than 2 unit parameters

You can define the abstract method as:

```
abstract member test : unit * unit -> unit
```